# how to configure NRPE to collect metric from different user?

Tags: node.js, nagios, pm2, nrpe

I am running my nodejs application under nodejs user. For monitoring i have installed check_pm2 under nodejs user. check_pm2 source (https://github.com/hobbyquaker/check_pm2). Now I configured NRPE with below command.

```
 command[check_pm2]= su  nodejs -c "/home/nodejs/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.2/bin/check_pm2 -A"
```

But in server i am getting response like

> "NRPE: Unable to read output"

on server.

Any solution to solve this?

Comment: Does the user that NRPE is running under have permissions to switch users?  Usually this is a privileged command.

Comment: Added below statement in sudoers file.

*nrpe    ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: /home/nodejs/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.2/bin/check_pm2*

Comment: That's not what I asked, that would give your nrpe user the ability to execute the check_pm2 script as root.  

What I was asking is the nrpe user allowed to run the su command? Because that is what it is doing as you have it defined.

Comment: Yes, nrpe user has permission to use "su", but sitll its failing.